# Define a custom finder method on an ActiveRecord relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

`Foo` has_many `Bar`. I want to do something like:

```
foo_instance.bars.find_with_custom_stuff(baz)
```

How do I define `find_with_custom_stuff` so that it's available on the `bars` relation? (and not just a `Bar` class method?)

**update**

I want to do something more complicated than a scope. something like:

```
def find_with_custom_stuff(thing)
  if relation.find_by_pineapple(thing)
    relation.find_by_pineapple(thing).monkey
  else
    :banana
  end
end
```

Comment: scopes on bar will be usable here.

Comment: what i want to add is a lot more complicated than a scope though.

Comment: you can do plenty of complicated stuff in a scope, can you elaborate?

Comment: updated the question. can i do that in a scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scopes, `scope` in rails 3 and `named_scope` in rails 2.

```
class Bar
  scope :custom_find, lambda {|baz| where(:whatever => baz) }
end

foo_instance.bars.custom_find(baz)
```

`scope` should return a scope, so given your update you probably don't want to use `scope` here.  You can write a class method though, and use `scoped` to access the current scope, like:

```
class Bar
  def self.custom_find(thing)
    if bar = scoped.find_by_pineapple(thing)
      bar.monkey
    else
      :banana
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @John Bachir: You probably don't want to create a method that finds a record and returns an attribute from it because it breaks expectations. This would be easier to understand if you used somewhat realistic examples. Consider `Post.find_tag('john')`; what does that return, and what is happening? Would you expect that it's really `Post.find_by_author_name('john').tags.first || 'untagged'`?

Comment: I think all the monkey business, so to speak, might have been just to illustrate the point?  e.g. if the method was `first_monkey` or something similar (and `:banana` was eliminated from the picture) I don't think this would really break expectations.  (but yeah, a method called find_by_custom_stuff that searches by pineapple and returns a monkey is probably pushing the limits of principle of least surprise :-P)

Comment: Confusing examples aside, I've realized that I want to make a scope/finder which returns something that is NOT an AR object -- and AR doesn't like that. So I ended up just making an instance method on the owning object.

Comment: Did you see the updated answer?  That's why I changed it to a class method, which will be fine and still operate on a relation, with the `scoped` variable exposing the current scope e.g. `user.bars`